# Bar plots with a single categorical and multiple descrete/continuous variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a summarized data as follows

Lab_Name Good_tests Bad_tests Total_tests
1      Main       1683        91         1774
2 District1        200      2569         2769
3 District2        106      1898         2004
4 District3         53       808          861
5 District4        115      1241         1356
6 District5         NA        NA            0

I am trying to plot a chart similar to this one from Excel

[![Barchat][2]][2]

```
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7DyF.png
```

I used the script below, but was unsuccessful

```
tidy_Data = df %>% 
  gather(key, value, Bad_tests, Good_tests)
tidy_Data
ggplot(aes(value)) + 
geom_density(aes(fill = key), show.legend = FALSE) + `
facet_grid(vars(Lab_Name), vars(key), scales = "free")
```

please help

Comment: Please `dput()` your data and add to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next code will help you to reach something similar:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
Data <- data.frame(LabName=c('Main',paste0('District',1:5)),
                   Good_tests=c(1683,200,106,53,115,0),
                   Bad_tests=c(91,2569,1898,808,1241,0),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Variables
Data$Total_tests <- Data$Good_tests+Data$Bad_tests

#Tidy and Plot
tidy_Data = Data %>% 
  gather(key, value, Bad_tests, Good_tests,Total_tests)

ggplot(tidy_Data,aes(x=LabName,y=value,fill=key)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
library(ggplot2)
tibble(lab = c("m", "d1", "d2"), gt = c(1683, 200, 106), bt = c(91, 2569, 1898)) %>%
  mutate(lab = paste(lab, gt, bt, sep = "\n")) %>%
  pivot_longer(-lab) %>%
  ggplot(aes(lab, value, fill = name, group = name)) +
  geom_col(position="dodge") +
  xlab(NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you